# How to add constraint for foreign key so it depends on value of column from table FK is coming from?

Tags: mysql, database, constraints

I need to set constraint so that table accepts foreign keys from other table only if another column in that table has specific value.

Database is quite complex but let me give example:

Table Foo:

```
Foo_id | Foo_value | Another values...
   1   |  "GOOD"   |
   2   |  "BAD"    |
   3   |  "GOOD"   |
```

Table Bar:

```
Bar_id | Foo_id(FK) | Another values...
   1   |     1      |
   2   |     1      |
   3   |     3      |
```

As you can see Bar should only accept accept id from Foo where Foo_Value is "GOOD".

I tried adding check constraint but it doesn't accept WHERE statement so I can't access Foo_Value. I tried searching but I can't really find anything or my explanation of this is wrong.

Comment: For anyone else finding this question since 2019, [MySQL does support CHECK constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-16-introducing-check-constraint) as of version 8.0.16.  Only simple calculations are supported, they are not able to inspect other tables, so triggers are still the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the only way is to use `trigger` (for insert/update):

```
create trigger chk_bar before insert on bar  /* before update */
for each row 
begin  
   if  not exists (SELECT 1 FROM foo 
                  WHERE Foo_value = 'GOOD' AND foo_id = new.foo_id)  then
       SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'   
       SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid FK';
   end if; 
end;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/EKY36936)**

Remember to add another trigger on `foo` on update `GOOD` -> `BAD` or delete that will check referential integrity.

Comment: Thanks for help, this will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL did not implement CHECK constraints until version 8.0.16.

You can enforce your rule with a foreign key only if the foreign key includes your Foo_value column. This means you need an extra KEY in your parent table.

```
ALTER TABLE Foo ADD UNIQUE KEY (Foo_id, Foo_value);

ALTER TABLE Bar ADD COLUMN Foo_value VARCHAR(4) DEFAULT 'GOOD',
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (Foo_id, Foo_value) REFERENCES Foo (Foo_id, Foo_value);
```

Since you can't use CHECK constraint, you must use triggers to ensure the Bar.Foo_value is 'GOOD':

```
CREATE TRIGGER BarInsertFooValueGood BEFORE INSERT ON Bar FOR EACH ROW
    SET Foo_value = 'GOOD';

CREATE TRIGGER BarUpdateFooValueGood BEFORE UPDATE ON Bar FOR EACH ROW
    SET Foo_value = 'GOOD';
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time and helping.